# SUMIFS function doesn't match right

Tags: excel, sumifs

Good afternoon,

I am having trouble with the sumifs function in Excel 2013. I have a huge sample of data with mostly numbers. I created a unique 'key' (simple added all the cells together: A1&B1 etc.). But if I use this key in the sumifs function as my criteria but Excel double counts some numbers. It looks like Excel cannot handle a very long criteria, the last numbers in the criteria are different but not according to Excel.

```
Number      Code1   Code2   Amount  Key         
123456789   111111  111112  1       123456789111111111112       
123456789   111111  111113  1       123456789111111111113
```

Above is a simplyfied version of my data. If I use the last column 'key' as the criteria in the sumifs formula the outcome is 2 instead of 1. Does anyone know how to fix this problem or which formula does the job?
Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, the amount column is the one which should be added.

Comment: This is because the values are being stored as `Number`s rather than `Text`.

Comment: What formula have you tried on your own?